# mysql avg in neighborhood dates

Tags: mysql, datetime, average

I have a table with

```
datetime (every 15 mins) | value
```

how I can show the avg value of

```
select  avg( value_15mins_before, value, value_15mins_after )
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Do you just want to add/sub 15 minutes to `value`? Please provide more information.

Comment: Please post some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you put an autoincrementing id in the table.  When using timestamps, things can be off by a fraction of a second, which can cause problems.

The following will give you a moving average around each point:

```
select (value + coalesce(tprev.value, 0.0) + coalesce(tnext.value, 0.0)) /
       ((case when value is not null then 1.0 else 0.0 end) +
        (case when tprev.value is not null then 1.0 else 0.0 end) +
        (case when tnext.value is not null then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
       ) as moving_avg
from (select t.*,
             (select max(t2.dt) from t t2 where t2.dt < t.dt) as dt_prev,
             (select min(t2.dt) from t t2 where t2.dt > t.dt) as dt_next
      from t
     ) t left outer join
     t tprev
     on t.dt_prev = tprev.dt_prev left outer join
     t tnext
     on t.dt_next = tnext.dt_next
```

It assumes that there are no "holes" in the data.  You can fix this by putting in constraints in the subquerys for dt_prev and dt_next . . . for instance, only considering time values that are within 20 minutes of the given value.

This also assumes that `value` is not null.